# How can I prevent picking up health items when I'm already at max health?

Tags: unity, c#

This is what I have so far..

```
public class Per10HealthCollect :MonoBehavior

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (GlobalHealth.healthValue >= 91)
        {
            GlobalHealth.healthValue = 100;
        }
        else
        {
            GlobalHealth.healthValue += 10;
        }
        GetComponent< CapsuleCollider>().Enabled = false;
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take time to preview and proofread your question when posting here. If your code isn't displayed clearly, with correct indenting and such, *don't post it* - instead consult the [help] for how to format it correctly. Also be sure to tag your question with the tech you're using - I'm guessing Unity based on the methods you're using?

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd add a constant to your GlobalHealth class to avoid spreading magic numbers all over your code. Now you can update it in just one place:

```
public class GlobalHealth {

    public const int MAX_HEALTH = 100;

    // ...
```

Now we can simplify your trigger method:

```
public class HealthPickup : MonoBehavior

    public int healthToAdd = 10;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // If we're already at max health, abort.
        // Don't change the health, don't consume the pickup.
        if (GlobalHealth.healthValue >= GlobalHealth.MAX_HEALTH)
            return;

        // We can use the Min function to choose the smaller of two values,
        // without doing the if-else ourselves. Less repetition, less chance of error! ;)
        GlobalHealth.healthValue = Mathf.Min(GlobalHealth.healthValue + healthToAdd,
                                             GlobalHealth.MAX_HEALTH);

        // Setting our game object to inactive will *also* disable the collider,
        // so we don't need to disable the collider separately.
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

If you modify the global health in multiple places, you might want to consider moving the clamping logic into that class, and just calling something like `GlobalHealth.Gain(healthToAdd)` - let GlobalHealth worry about enforcing its own limits.

Comment: Or, if your character's max health isn't a constant, you can implement whatever logic you want that determines the character's max health using a read-only property within your entity class - for example: `public int maxHealth { get { return 100 + level * 10 + numMaxHealthUpgrades * 30; } }` This way, if you ever want to change the way your max health is calculated, you only have to do it in one place.